# Delta Method for confidence intervals in online A/B testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, estimation, delta-method

Scenario:  I have two groups (treatment and control) that are matched to each other during a "pre" period.  That is, controls were chosen such that their behavior in times before the treatment correlated well with the group that eventually was subjected to treatment.

After treatment periods I want to compare the effect of treatment by finding the difference between the expected or organic behavior growth in the treatment group and the actual treatment behavior.  The expected behavior is calculated by a linear regression between treatment and control groups during the "pre" period and assuming this functional relationship persists after the treatment period.

$$
Y_{expected} = A X_{t>t_{0}} + B
$$

Where $t_0$ is the treatment time and $X_{t>t_0}$ is the observed control group values after treatment.  The effect is then found by
$$
L = \frac{Y_{t>t_0} - Y_{expected}}{Y_{expected}}
$$

My question is now: Is it necessary to use the Delta Method to find a confidence interval for $L$?

I know $Y_{expected}$ is a functional transformation of the random observation $X_{t>t_0}$ but it is not clear to me why I can't simply find confidence bounds for $Y_{expected}$ by measuring the variation in the residuals $Y_{t<t_0} - Y_{pre-expected}$ during the pre-treatment time.